# Refactor directive so controller method is only called once while maintaining two-way binding?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a newbie to AngularJS and have exhausted Google and the egghead.io videos on isolate scope trying to solve this -- sorry if this has been covered before but I need some help.

I have a directive (`<span status-label>`) which passes a person object (`$scope.data.jack`) from a data attribute (`item=`) to the template using isolate scope.

Within this directive's `controller` function, I've defined a function that calculates a person object's status and returns it (`get_status(item)`). Based on the returned status, the directive template changes (the `get_status` function is extremely simplified for purposes of the example).

In the simplified example below, I'm calling the `get_status` function inside the template via `ng-show``, once for each status, meaning that as the number of statuses increase, so will the number of times the function has to be called. This seems very inefficient.

How can I refactor this example so `get_status` needs to only be called once, while maintaining two-way binding between the internal person objects and parent person objects? I tried using the '&' designator on the directive isolate scope to create a template variable that mapped to the result of `get_status(item)` but had no luck. Thanks in advance.

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/lDkTcA?p=info

*Directive HTML:*

```
<div ng-controller='BaseController'>
  <p>{{ data.jill.name }}: <span status-label item='data.jill'></span></p>
  <p>{{ data.jack.name }}: <span status-label item='data.jack'></span></p>
</div>
```

*BaseController*:

```
angular.module('familyApp').controller('BaseController',
  function ($scope) {
    $scope.data = {
      jack: {name: 'Jack', age: 40, flagged: false},            
      jill: {name: 'Jill', age: 30, flagged: true}
    }; 
  });
```

*statusLabel directive*:

```
  angular.module('familyApp').directive('statusLabel',
    function ($compile, $parse) {
        return {
            controller: function ($scope) {
              $scope.get_status = function (item) {
                if (item.flagged === true) {
                  return 1;
                } else {
                  return 0;
                }
              };                        
            },
            scope: {
              'item': '=',
            },
            template: '<div ng-show="get_status(item) == 1">Flagged (<a href ng-click="item.flagged = false">Unflag</a>)</div><div ng-show="get_status(item) == 0">Clean (<a href ng-click="item.flagged = true">Flag</a>)</div>'
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would offer better performance, but you can create a watch on the value of the get_status function.

```
$scope.$watch(function() { 
    return $scope.get_status($scope.item);
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.status = newValue;
});
```

Then use this value in your template.

```
template: '<div ng-show="status === 1">Flagged (<a href ng-click="item.flagged = false">Unflag</a>)</div><div ng-show="status === 0">Clean (<a href ng-click="item.flagged = true">Flag</a>)</div>'
```

I updated your plunk here: http://plnkr.co/edit/l6Osy43zInSE66ixq9Nj?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking this approach would be simpler.   Basically introduce another scope variable, set it in your get_status function and then refer to it as needed within the template.

```
    function ($compile, $parse) {
      return {
        controller: function ($scope) {
            **$scope.isFlagged = getstatus($scope.item);**

            function getstatus(item) {
            if (item.flagged === true) {
              return true;  

            } else {
              return false;  

            }

          };                        
        },
        scope: {
          'item': '=',
        },
       template: '<div ng-show="isFlagged">Flagged (<a href ng-click="item.flagged = false">Unflag</a>)</div><div ng-show="!isFlagged">Clean (<a href ng-click="item.flagged = true">Flag</a>)</div>'
    };
});
```

Note that I simplified your original `ng-show` logic as well...   Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/rem70/Nrz5C/